# Stock update using REST API PUT Method gives error 'Invalid content type' Magento 2

Tags: php, rest, magento, magento2.2

I am using magento2 Rest API to update the quantity of product by sku and testing on postman and it gives error

> Content-Type header is invalid.400 Bad Request.

I have generated the consumer key, consumer secret, Access token and Access token secret key.

Below are the setting done in postman -:

Method: PUT

**URL**:  http://127.0.0.1/pos_mage/rest/V1/products/{sku_of_product}

**Authorisation**: OAuth2.0 and set the access token value

**Header**: Key: Content-Type and Value: application/json

**Body**: Key: stockItems and Value : 10

But when i am trying to run the API it gives me error

{
    "message": "Content-Type header is invalid."
}
400 Bad Request.

I am testing on my localhost.

I have checked many tutorial but still not success-:

[Magento 2 - REST API PUT product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140175/magento-2-rest-api-put-product)

[Why "Invalid Content Type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28181325/why-invalid-content-type)

[Magento 2 Updating Stock via Rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50508478/magento-2-updating-stock-via-rest-api)

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a REST API with a JSON payload, 400 error code are typically used to indicate that the JSON is invalid in some way according to the API specification for the service .

Check whether the request contain a valid JSON format or try the following :

```
ContentType = "application/json" and Accept = "Application/json"
```

Comment: Thanks Radwan but the solution you have shared is not working.